# How can I assemble a minimal working MIPS program?

Tags: c, assembly, mips, simulator

I can run this assembly code in my [simulator](http://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/eit090/MipsIt/MipsITEnvRef.html) but I get a linker warning

```
Linking...
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol start; defaulting to 80020000
Post build...

Done
```

Why do I get this error with solely the assembly code and not with C code that does the same? How can I change my assembly to make the linker happy? I'd like to know which statements are not necessary so that I can have a minimal program?

I could comment out these statement (that I'm not sure what they do):

```
#.frame $fp,40,$31      # vars= 16, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
#.mask  0xc0000000,-4
#.fmask 0x00000000,0
```

My code (that was translated from C) is

```
    .file   1 "minimips.c"

 # -G value = 8, Cpu = 3000, ISA = 1
 # GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404 (mips-mips-ecoff) compiled by GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404.
 # options passed:  -msoft-float
 # options enabled:  -fpeephole -ffunction-cse -fkeep-static-consts
 # -fpcc-struct-return -fcommon -fverbose-asm -fgnu-linker -msoft-float
 # -meb -mcpu=3000

gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "Result %d\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    #.frame $fp,40,$31      # vars= 16, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    #.mask  0xc0000000,-4
    #.fmask 0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,40
    sw  $31,36($sp)
    sw  $fp,32($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    jal __main
    li  $2,40           
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    li  $2,40           
    sw  $2,20($fp)
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $3,20($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    sw  $2,24($fp)
    la  $4,$LC0
    lw  $5,24($fp)
    jal printf
    move    $2,$0
    j   $L1
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,36($sp)
    lw  $fp,32($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,40
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

To begin with I'm just adding numbers. The C code was a+b=c.

### Update

When I translated a simpler program (without any includes) then I can create a project type assembly (and not combined C/asm).

It now compiles and runs without linker error (but it doesn't use `printf`)

```
gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,40,$31      # vars= 16, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,40
    sw  $31,36($sp)
    sw  $fp,32($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    jal __main
    li  $2,15           # 0x0000000a
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    li  $2,20           # 0x00000014
    sw  $2,20($fp)
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $3,20($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    sw  $2,24($fp)
    move    $2,$0
    j   $L1
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,36($sp)
    lw  $fp,32($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,40
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

Comment: Well, the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. What's your question?

Comment: @CarlNorum Why the linker is not happy and what I can do about it. I removed the includes from the C and then it was ok. I'm not sure if the assembly can write to the console if I don't link. I'd like the asm code to be able to do console i/o but it's not necessary right now. So I removed the includes and then it was ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C library defines a special symbol called `start` which is where the program starts execution. The linker expects to find this symbol, which it will use as the program entry point.

You didn't define `start` so the linker complains and gives you a default value. The default is probably the first instruction of your code, so that's why the program still works.